# Using rsync with the verbose option and filtering the information displayed

Tags: directory, rsync, display, options, filter

I am using `rsync` with the `-a` `-r` and `-v` options to copy files and directories from one server to another.

This all works fine.  But when I make a change, for example, to a single file on the source and run `rsync`, every directory is displayed as well as the modified file.

Is there away that I could only see the files that were modified or new files displayed on the screen (stdout) and not the whole directory structure ?

Eg: `file.txt` is in directory `test` and there is another directory `test1` which is at the same level as `test`.  If I modify `file.txt` and run `rsync`

#### Output:

```
/test/
/test/file.txt
/test1/
```

Comment: can't you just grep? `grep -v '/$'`